# Rails: Extra unnecessary queries when including a M2M table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance, many-to-many, find

Say I've got a Teachers table with a :has_and_belongs_to_many relationship with a Students table. I have a students_teachers table, mapping the fields [teacher_id, student_id].

When I perform a find and wish to bring up all teachers with all their students, I do a:

```
Teacher.find(:all, :include => :students)
```

although I've included the students table, I still end up with one query bringing up the teachers, and then n more queries for the students_teachers table, while n is the number of teachers that returned from the first query.

Why doesn't Rails already join on the students_teachers table and instead sends so many queries?

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behaviour of Rails' eager loading, to prevent the N+1 problem (i.e. having to run a query to find all the teachers and then another query per teacher to find all their students.) See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations.

If you want to do it in fewer queries, you'd need to use `:joins`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though replacing include with joins doesn't produce the expected result. What should be the syntax if I wish to be left with an array of Teachers objects and their students association working? (consider the fact there could be a condition on the Teachers find call),